# how get element by class name from while loop?

Tags: javascript

following code is working with ID but not working with class name, i am using this code in loop hence i can not use ID. Please suggest ... :-

```js
function myFunction() {
  var new1 = document.getElementByClassName("bookBedNo").value;
  document.getElementById("my").value = new1;
}
```

```html
<td><input class='bookBedNo' type='text' name='bedNo' value="BD002" readonly ></td>

<input type="text" id="my" value="abc">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: use  `document.getElementsByClassName("bookBedNo")[0].value`

Answer (score 1):

`getElementByClassName` is not a function, you meant `getElementsByClassName` (`Elements` plural).

Since `getElementsByClassName` returns an Array-like structure, take the 0th index out to get your element.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var new1 = document.getElementsByClassName("bookBedNo")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("my").value = new1;
}
```

```html
<td><input class='bookBedNo' type='text' name='bedNo' value="BD002" readonly ></td>

<input type="text" id="my" value="abc">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

You could also use `querySelector` to get just one element based of that class:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var new1 = document.querySelector(".bookBedNo").value;
  document.querySelector("#my").value = new1;
}
```

```html
<td><input class='bookBedNo' type='text' name='bedNo' value="BD002" readonly ></td>

<input type="text" id="my" value="abc">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```